# Main.Type does not have a member named 'motionManager' [Swift]

Tags: ios, swift, program-entry-point, core-motion

I'm using CoreMotion to register changes in activity type. I've been having issues with creating a CMMotionActivityHandler and with using it in the startActivityUpdatesToQueue function. Now I'm getting the errors "Main.Type does not have a member named motionManager" and "Main does not have a member named handler" despite clearly creating and initializing these variables. What am I doing wrong?

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import CoreMotion
import CoreLocation

public class Main {

    let motionManager = CMMotionActivityManager()
    var motionAvailable = CMMotionActivityManager.isActivityAvailable()
    var activityType = CMMotionActivity()
    typealias CMMotionActivityHandler = (CMMotionActivity!) -> Void
    let handler = CMMotionActivityHandler(motionManager) //Main.Type does not have a member named 'motionManager'
    public var testResult = "Not working"

    func run() -> String {

        if motionAvailable == true {

        motionManager.startActivityUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), withHandler: handler) //Main does not have a member named 'handler'
        testResult = "Updating"

        }
        else {

        testResult = "No M8"
        }

        if activityType == CMMotionActivity().stationary {

        testResult == "Stationary"
        }
        else {

        testResult == "Not Stationary"
        }
    }

    init () {
    self.run()
    }
```

Comment: You can't initialize `handler` to a new instance of `CMMotionActivityHandler`. Instead you need to create a block (piece of code treated like an object) that has the same type (argument types and return types) as a `CMMotionActivityHandler`.

Comment: You create the block like this: `let handler:CMMotionActivityHandler = { (activity:CMMotionActivity?) ➝ Void in ... }`. Not handler can be passed as an argument to `startActivityUpdatesToQueue(_:, withHandler:)`.

Comment: Also, your block will be invoked at a later time by Core Motion when it wants to report activity changes, so you set up your callback, then let your app run.

Comment: I put a snippet here: https://gist.github.com/nielsbot/ba06510907886bae5ae7

Comment: @nielsbot: I have closed as a duplicate because it seemed like the same problem to me: A property cannot be initialized in terms of other properties of the same class. If you think this is a different problem here then I'll reopen the question.